# WIX: How to mix a variable and a property

Tags: wix

Wix related question: this are  the snipets from the product.wxs

```
<?define SourceSolutionItems="D:\Dev\Net\Projects\Ge_Portal\Ter.Portal\Ter.Portal\Tm.Ter.Web"?>


    <Property Id="CONFIGURATION_PROPERTY">CIT</Property>
```

I Would like to combine this, because the value from the property **CONFIGURATION_PROPERTY** is set in a separate UI dialog.

Currently i have this:

```
 <Component Id="ConfigFiles_CIT" Guid="{D67B38EE-5658-4A32-8C56-7120B835FFC1}">
          <File Id="WebConfig_CIT" Source="$(var.SourceSolutionItems)\ConfigurationFiles\CIT\web.config" Name="web.Config" />
          <Condition>CONFIGURATION_PROPERTY="CIT"</Condition>
        </Component>
```

This part is used for every radio selection possible. So the config file will be installed from the specific subfolder. So far it is working good, my problem is that i am getting lots of warning when i compile it:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbJtn.jpg
[image]
I tried thinks like:

```
 <Component Id="ConfigFiles_CIT" Guid="{D67B38EE-5658-4A32-8C56-7120B835FFC1}">
              <File Id="WebConfig_CIT" Source="$(var.SourceSolutionItems)\ConfigurationFiles\[**CONFIGURATION_PROPERTY**]\web.config" Name="web.Config" />

            </Component>
```

I also tired changing the `?define SourceSolutionItems="`  part to combine it,  without any success.

Comment: The warning simply indicates that there are two components that install the same file into the same folder. The compiler does not evaluate conditions because those are evaluated at runtime. Instead, it simply displays a warning and let you continue. If you are sure those conditions are mutually exclusive, you can safely ignore the warning.

Comment: I understand this, however, i would still want to know if it is possible to mix a variable and a property.

Answer (score 0):

Precompiler processing instructions (`<?if`, `<?define`...) and variables (`$(var.varname)`) are processed *before* the actual candle processing of the WiX XML file.

Therefore it's even possible to have something like

```
<?define varname=Path[PropertyName]MorePath ?>
```

The candle/light process will only see

```
<File Source="Path[PropertyName]MorePath" />
```

instead of

```
<File Source="$(var.varname)" />
```

For details, please refer to the [documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/preprocessor.html).

Comment: I have tried the <?define varname=Path[PropertyName]MorePath ?> aproach, but i still get the error: The system cannot find the file ... because it uses [PropertyName]. I think i let it the way it is with the many warnings, but functional.